# Unable to host python server

Tags: python, sockets, server

When I try to host server in python on my local network (using my local ip) it works properly, but when I try to do it with my public ip so that i can access server from any device which is not connected to my network, program(server program) gives an error.

**server.bind(ADDR)**

**OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context**

I need to know why and how can I make it work.

HERE IS WORKING CODE:

```
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
```

HERE IS NOT WORKING CODE:

```
PORT = 5050
SERVER = '' #<here i put my public ip>
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
```

Comment: What port are you using ?

Comment: Please give us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you better. You write that you have some code that seems to work, and some that don't. Please include examples of both in the question.

Comment: I have used different ports such as 5050, 5555, 80, 8080 (non worked for public ip)  and also added working and not working code.

Comment: Can you print out the `SERVER` variable in the first example?

Comment: Yes, it printed my local ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a socket to *your public IP address*, because this is the IP address of your router. You have to bind your socket to your local IP address and create a port forwarding in your router to your local computer.

**Find your local ip address**

If you are on windows, type `ipconfig` in the Windows *cmd* shell and search for *IPv4 Address: xxx.xxx.x.xx*. On Linux you type in `ifconfig` and search for *eth0* and the *inet* address.

Use this local ip for `SERVER`.

**Port forwarding**

Choose a port. You can check if the port number conflicts with any official port in this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Then go into your router's settings and enable *Port forwarding* for this port. Depending on what kind of router you have, you can open the port there and select a target device, your computer, to forward incoming connections to. Use the local ip of your computer and the port you set in `PORT` in your python socket server.

**Connect from another device**

To connect to your computer from outside of your local network, use your public IP address and the port you chose.

Comment: Problem is I am currently using usb dongle which dont support port forwarding.

Comment: I'm afraid running a socket server that can be reached from outside is not possible then.

Comment: Is there any other way I can host server using python which can be accessed by other computers.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Usually the ISPs block all incoming connections to USB dongles, to protect you from possible attacks. You can still host your own server on a hosting provider, but you would most probably have to pay for this service.